# How to modify template tags function?

Tags: template-tags

By default, get_user_meta returns an array, a single value or false. I want to change the return value somehow. How to do that?

I want to modify the return type of a template tag get_user_meta inside the class only.
How to do this? I am trying this:-

```
class modifyUserMeta {
    function modifyUserMeta(){
        add_filter('get_user_meta',$this->modifyMeta);
    }
    function modifyMeta(){
    //how can i modify the return type of get_user_meta?
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a little more detail. It is hard to know what you are asking or what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to modify the return result of get_user_meta. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `get_user_meta` filter. Despite WP often having filters same as function name, it isn't the rule exactly.

There is however deeper filter in more generic [`get_metadata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_metadata/) function:

```
$check = apply_filters( "get_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single );

if ( null !== $check ) {
    if ( $single && is_array( $check ) )
        return $check[0];
    else
        return $check;
}
```

Also your PHP is a mess with callback there. All together:

```
class modifyUserMeta {

    function modifyUserMeta(){

        add_filter('get_user_metadata', array($this, modifyMeta), 10, 4 );
    }

    function modifyMeta( $null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single ){

        // check ID, key, and format then return accordingly
    }
}
```